# Regular Expression for zipcode pattern?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to write regular expression  for zipcode pattern? I need to makesure that all zipcodes(sample addresses) are 5 digits, but my query is not working.

```
with table1 as(
select "123 6th St. Melbourne, FL 32904" as address union all
select "71 Pilgrim Avenue, Chevy Chase, MD 20815"  union all
select "70 Bowman St. South Windsor, CT 06074" union all
select "4 Goldfield Rd. Honolulu, HI 966815"  union all
select "44 Shirley Ave. West Chicago, IL 60185" union all
select "514 S. Magnolia St. Orlando, FL 32806 "
)
select address,regexp_contains("address",r"\s\d{5}$")check from table1
```

Comment: One problem is you are checking that the last char is a digit and for the last example ("514 S. Magnolia St. Orlando, FL 32806 "), the last char is a space.

I am downvoting this question because you don't explain what happens when you run this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least remove quotes around address in regexp_contains

```
select address, regexp_contains(address, r"\s\d{5}$") check from table1
```

Also you might want to revisit use of `$` at the end of regex

Consider `r"\b\d{5}\b"` as an option